# Timestamp being saved as DateTime by Laravel - SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value:

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime

I receive a date from my frontend and need to save it as a UNIX timestamp on my Laravel API.
The date will either be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` or just simply the date as `YYYY-MM-DD`

In my model I've defined mutators and accessors to convert the date to timestamp and vice versa. From what I've read in the docs and online this is the right way to do it.

```
public function setStartAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['start'] = strtotime($value);
}

public function getStartAttribute($value)
{
    $value = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($value)->toDateTimeString(); 
    return $value;
}
```

I've defined the fields as `timestamp` in my migration as well...

```
$table->timestamp('start')->nullable()->default(null);
```

And finally the controller creating the entry...

```
$entry = entry::create([
     'name' => $request->name,
     'description' => $request->description,
     'type' => $request->type,
     'start' => $request->start,
]);
```

But I still get the error `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1615381200' for column 'start' at row 1` whenever I'm trying to create a new entry.
Why is it trying to save it as a `datetime` value after I've converted it into a timestamp?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL timestamp is different from a time in PHP. The format of a time in PHP is seconds since UNIX epoch, but a MySQL is just a formatted datetime in the range '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. Maybe this is stored in the same way, but to save it, you can just give it a datetime string. In your case you can just omit the mutators and it will work.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem through. I need to save the Date as a timestamp not in a date time format. How do I correctly save it then as a Timestamp between Laravel and MySQL? What about saving the timestamp as an integer as its just seconds since epoch?

Comment: @user931018 If you just want to save the seconds than one of the integer variants (probably bigInt) should work.